# Symfony Mercure with Docker compose

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, mercure

I am trying to post private mercury updates, i follow the symfony documentation from near, as indicated I do this :

```
$update = new Update(
  'https://example.com/books/1',
   json_encode(['status' => 'OutOfStock']),
   true
);

 
$hub->publish($update);
```

My docker compose file :

```
 mercure:
  restart: unless-stopped
  image: dunglas/mercure
  environment:
    SERVER_NAME: :1337
    MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |
      anonymous 0
      cors_origins https://localhost:8080
    MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
    MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!'
  ports:
    - 1337:1337
  volumes:
    - mercure_data:/data
    - mercure_config:/config
```

My project is in HTTPS but not the mercury hub.
At the time of publication I get this error message :

`"Couldn't connect to server for \"http://mercure/.well-known/mercure\"."`

I even tried this url :
`http://localhost:1337/.well-known/mercure`

but nothing changes.

I checked the generated jwt, I found that it is different from the one sent in the cookie, but even by putting a correct jwt manually I still have the same error

Comment: mercure needs to be reachable from external. (the browser socket opens only via https directly to mercure). so you have to add a proxy in front (as you most likly have already for the api interface. nginx or apache with https termination - add a second on the same domain. be aware the way you communicate with mercure is different then the browser.. your "external_uri" is the full https adress.

Comment: @Rufinus Hey, since my post, I managed to make the request without error by doing a "http://mercure:1337/.well-known/mercure" except that this time I do not see the console.log in the: eventSource. onmessage = e => {
         console.log(e)
       }